# Как грамотнее оформить предложение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

**Можно я скину факты, которые писал подруге, и она все равно не поверила?** 
Как-то нелепо получается.

Comment: Если Вы хотите, чтобы Вам помогли оформить предложение, сообщите, кому предназначено высказывание, в какой форме, в какой ситуации? Именно от речевой ситуации зависит выбор языковых средств.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно нужен контекст. Но в качестве первого приближения стоит, возможно, рассмотреть вариант: *Можно я скину факты, **о которых** писал подруге(,) **и/но которым** она все равно не поверила?*

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, писать так, как написано у behemothus, но заменить "скину факты" на "сообщу факты".Получиться так:"Можно я сообщу факты, о которых писал подруге, но которым она все равно не поверила?"

Comment: Да, пожалуй. Даже если ситуация позволяет использовать компьютерный сленг, то "скидывают" все-же файлы, смс, а не факты.

Comment: Если этот неофициальное общение, вполне можно и "факты скинуть". Например, "телефончик скинь"- т.е. "пришли сообщение с номером телефона" - фраза уже вполне обычная. Вполне нормальное явление метонимии в разговорной речи, которая стремится к краткости.

Comment: конечно, "скинуть факты" - жаргон. Но я не заморачивался ещё и этим.

Comment: А мне, например, "режет ухо" фраза "скинь факты".